# asp.net custom control used in user control (ascx) - how to catch on load error?

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, custom-controls

I have a custom control that is placed on a user control(ascx).   In the load of the custom control happens an error.  I would like to "catch" this error in the user control(ascx). How could I do this?

Default aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title></title></head>
<body><form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="test" Text="hello world"></asp:Label>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
</form></body></html>
```

WebUserControl1.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<%@ Register tagPrefix="test" namespace="WebApplication1" assembly="WebApplication1" %>
<test:MyControl runat="server" ID="test2" Text="test"></test:MyControl>
```

WebUserControl1.ascx.vb:

```
Public Class WebUserControl1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl


    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
            'Doesn't work!
            MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        Catch ex As Exception
            handleException(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Page_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Error
        'Doesn't work!
        handleException(New Exception())
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   End Sub

    Private Sub handleException(ByVal ex As Exception)
        Me.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("ex.tostring"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

And last but not least:  my custom control:

MyControl.vb:

```
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Throw New Exception("")
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would like to be able to catch this error, in the *.ascx file   this seems not be possible? Or is it?

Comment: This isn't going to be possible because the user control doesn't initiate the `OnLoad` - the only place to catch this exception is in `Application_Error`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot intercept exceptions thrown in events like `OnLoad`, `OnInit`, `OnPreRender` etc. within a parent control.

You can try to do that in the Page/UserControl by attaching to `Page.Error` event.

A better alternative is to add a global error handler in `global.asax` file in the `Application_Error` event handler.

Comment: This could be a possible solution if only I could know which usercontrol(ascx) gave the error.   If I attach to the page.error in a usercontrol and have 2 usercontrols on the page,  they both would receive this page.error event.

Comment: You can attach the handler on UserControl.Error as well.